# Most efficient solution: trim, capitalise and explode by comma for a string

Tags: php, string, trim, ucfirst

I have a string like so:

```
Quaint village location, seaside views, four bedrooms
```

I need to do the following:

- Take each comma separated item and add it into an array
- Remove whitespace from beginning and end
- Capitalise the first letter

So for example, the above string becomes:

```
array(
   [0] => 'Quaint village location',
   [1] => 'Seaside views',
   [2] => 'Four bedrooms',
)
```

I have started this code block using `trim`, `explode` and `ucfirst` but I don't think I'm going about it a very efficient way.

```
iif(get_field('property_information') != NULL){
        $raw_facilities_list = explode(",", get_field('property_information'));
        $other_facilities_list = [];
        foreach($raw_facilities_list as $facility){
            $facility = trim($facility);
            $facility = ucfirst($facility);
            array_push($other_facilities_list,$facility);
        }
        $property['extra_features'] = $other_facilities_list;
        echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($property);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

What is the most efficient way to perform these 3 tasks?

Answer (score 2):

Simply using `array_map` along with `explode`

```
$property['extra_features'] = array_map(function($v){
  return ucfirst(trim($v));
},explode(',',$str));
```

**Output:**

```
array(
   [0] => 'Quaint village location',
   [1] => 'Seaside views',
   [2] => 'Four bedrooms',
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/449664)

Comment: What if I don't want to print it? I instead want to add it to another, bigger array: `property['extra_features'] = $other_facilities_list;`

Comment: you can `explode(', ',$str)` and avoid the `trim`

Comment: @AlexAndrei I don't think that's a great idea

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right; you could split it up into some parts, though:

```
function sanitize($string){
    return ucfirst(trim($string));
}

function treat($sentence)
{
    return join(",",(array_map('sanitize',explode(",",$sentence))));
}


$array[] = treat("Quaint village location, seaside views, four bedrooms");
```